# How to make JS draw elemnts in expected order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem. There is some script that takes 2-5 seconds to complete and during this time I want to decorate the screen with loder gif. If there is no data it should display message that data is not awailable and otherwise it should draw graphs.
But what happens if I have the code that requests data and process graphs the loader does not apper as it waits till everythin is processed and only then appears and immedeatly is replaced by graph.
If I comment the code with the request. The message that data is not awailable appears right away(and it should not) and then the loader shows itself and then after an instance it desappears leaving just the message. As you can see on the screenshot the message and the loader apper simulteneously but the should not. 
I assume tha JS first process all operations and then draw the result right away, not following my order. How can I tell the JS that it should process my comand(draw the loader) and only then process other things? Would be very greatful for your help.

```
    <div class="main-container-right">
            <!-- Графики -->
            <div class="graph-container" style="display: none;">
              <div id="mass-time-graph-container" class="derivative-graph-container"> -</div>
              <div id="temperature-graph-container" class="temperature-graph-container">-</div>
            </div>
            <div class="no-data-message data-not-awailable" style="display: none;">Data is not awailable</div>
            <div class="no-data-message data-loading" style="display: none;">
              <img class="waiting-animation" src="img/loading.gif" title="Данные подгружаются" style="margin-left: 5px; cursor: pointer;">
              <div>Data is loading</div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Графиков -->
          </div>
```

```
// -- Выбор испытания
    $('body').on('click', '.tr-content', function(){
        $('.data-not-awailable').fadeOut(1)
// -- THE Message should be display none
        $('.graph-container').fadeOut(1)
// -- THE Loader should display
        $('.data-loading').fadeIn()
        
// -- SOME code that takes 2-5 second

            $('.graph-container').fadeOut(1)
// -- THE Loader should display none
            $('.data-loading').fadeOut(1)
// -- THE Message should be display
            $('.data-not-awailable').fadeIn(1)

    })
```

[image]

I solved the problem by placing the code bellow  $('.data-loading').fadeIn() into a function. And placed the function into window.setTimeout(). I've got that it is important to send link to the function - func not func(). Suppose that it is evident for experienced coders but for me it was a kind of insight. 
`window.setTimeout(processSelectedTest, 100)`
Thank you all. Your comments helped me alot to direct my search.

Comment: The behavior you're getting makes sense because it doesn't get the instruction to "wait" anywhere before going to the next line. I think it's important to add the  *SOME code that takes 2-5 second* part, as that is probably the part where the solution lies. Especially if that part contains some asynchronous code.

Comment: the part expected to run after that long code finished performing its action, should be called after the event occurred. Like you did, each of those instructions are performed one after the other in terms of instants. The code that performs that long action might not be sync (and it shouldn't anyway because it would lock the UI otherwise) so it's returning immediately letting the next instructions to be executed. If you have control over the code you didn't include here (taking 2-5 secs), you should make it so you can pass it a callback that will be invoked when it finished.

Comment: The issue is that javascript is *single threaded* - and this *includes* drawing/updating the page.  So either "some code" is async and all your code runs at once, or, it's not (which I suspect) but the page can't be updated because your code is running - when your code finishes it does all the updates at once.

Comment: The general consensus appears to be:  code to show "loading", then code to run and hide loading inside a `setTimeout()` (don't put the hide loading outside the setTimeout...).   But linked answers are from ~2010 - while still relevant, there may be a more modern solution such as using await/async, Promise or `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: [This thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21081) (from *25 years ago*) makes the same request.  In this case it was marked as won't fix (16 years ago) with the suggestion that *"the right solution here really ought to be worker threads for the long-running script processing."*

Comment: `window.setTimeout(processSelectedTest, 100)` could also be `window.setTimeout(() => processSelectedTest(), 100)` or `window.setTimeout(function() { processSelectedTest() ), 100)` - setTimeout needs a function, not the result of a function.